# JavaScript annotated documentation (JSDoc): should @memberOf specify "prototype" as well?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, memberof

Example:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 * @Returns {AStar}
 */
function AStar() {


};

/**
 * @public
 *
 * Should this be:
 * @memberOf {AStar.prototype}
 * Or: 
 * @memberOf {AStar}
 *
 * @param {Number} startX
 * @param {Number} startY
 * @param {Number} destinationX
 * @param {Number} destinationY
 * @returns {Path}
 */
AStar.prototype.getPath = function(startX, startY, destinationX, destinationY) {
//(...)
};
```

For the function "getPath" added to AStar's prototype as in the code snipped above, should the annotated documentations on the "getPath" function specify:

```
@memberOf {AStar.prototype}
```

or

```
@memberOf {AStar}
```

?

Comment: I think according to this: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-memberof.html it should be AStar.prototype. In AStar you can have `this.position={};` and that would be a member of AStar. Another programmer would conclude that getPath would be shared by AStar instances but isn't a direct member.

Answer (score 2):

The JavaScript code declares `getPath` as a method of `AStar` objects. If you do not provide the `@memberOf` tag, jsdoc is able to determine this by itself: the documentation lists `getPath` as a method of `AStar` objects. So you do not need to use either `@memberOf` options you cite in the question.

Moreover, in the specific case in your question jsdoc won't use your `@memberof` tag *unless* you use the form with the exclamation mark `@memberof!`. The form without the mark can be ignored by jsdoc if it thinks that it knows better than you what the method is a member of. The form with the exclamation mark forces jsdoc to not ignore it. So to have an effect on the documentation, you'd have to use `@memberof!`.